# How to call Bamboo HR API call from SharePoint Online

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, sharepoint-online, crossdomain-request.js

I would like to get data from Bamboo HR and display it in SharePoint Online. Bamboo HR supports [API with basic authentication](https://www.bamboohr.com/api/documentation/) to call and get data from Bamboo HR. When I tried to get data in browser, it's working fine however when I use ajax call inside Script Editor Webpart in SharePoint, it gives me cross origin error. I also tried with jsonp using $.getJSON however it's also giving an error as below:

```
function test(a,b,c){debugger;
   console.log(a);
}

$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/test/v1/time_off/requests/?start=2018-04-25&end=2018-04-25&status=approved",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json",
        'Authorization': "Basic api_key:x")
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'test',
});
```

Above code throwing below error in SharePoint Online environment.

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/test/v1/time_off/requests/?start=2018-04-25&end=2018-04-25&status=approved&callback=test&_=1524995081404'
>   because its MIME type ('text/xml') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled.

Any help to retrieve data from Bamboo HR into SharePoint will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Here are two ways for your reference:

1.**Pushing data to SharePoint list using RESTful service**.

Create a job and push the data from Bamboo HR to SharePoint List using REST API of CSOM(C#).

2.**Using Business Connectivity Service(BCS)**.

[Manage Business Connectivity Service Applications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-business-connectivity-service-applications-2ced10aa-db9a-4828-a7a5-e47a57c3a823)

Comment: What if I need live data from Bamboo HR. Bamboo HR already published data with live api then why can't we directly bind it with SharePoint?

Comment: check the BCS feature.